# Python reading from csv file, same strings with "-" sign doesn't match

Tags: python, csv

I have written a program that looks through all items in a csv file and checks if a given input is in the list. It compares two strings based on the == operator: one string from the **program** and one from the **file**. Everything worked fine until one of the values had "-" in it. For some reason even though those two strings look identical to me when I compare them in if statement they do not match.

```
word = "Don Ho – Notepad ++"
if(word == word_from_file):
    print("They are the same")
```

So I have copied the above string from my source code to the file and I've printed all the values from my file to console and he Don Ho - Notepad++ got printed as "Don Ho â€“ Notepad ++" even though I copied the name from the above code and pasted it in my file. Both files use UFT-8. I copied the "Don Ho - Notepad++" from elsewhere and pasted it in the csv file and then it got printed as "Don Ho - Notepad++" but the comparison still doesn't work.

Any ideas what could be causing it?

Comment: It's not an ASCII hyphen, it's a Unicode character that looks similar, like an em-dash or en-dash.

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like you have different hyphen-like symbols there. `-` is ASCII hyphen or minus sign, but there are also UTF-8 hyphens (more than one, I think).

Comment: There are multiple types of dashes; for instance this-one and—this one.

Comment: Hi it appears you were right. It seems like when I copied the name from the ANSI file from which I gathered data and copied it over to my UFT-8 file csv, the sign got converted to some other UFT-8 sign that for human eye look the same, or at least for me. When I changed it to the - sign that is under upper keypad on my keyboard, from minus sign that is on the right and made sure the formatting is same it finally worked. Thank for the help.